# Efficient comparison based set-like data structure for insertion and lookup but no deletion

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, containers

Structures like AVL-Tree and RB-Tree should be fast enough for most uses. But is there any room for optimization if there is no need for deletion?

To be specific, I wonder if there is a container type optimized for the scenario described below:

1. It's set-like, i.e. it stores unique values.
2. It's based on comparison, e.g. `<` operator, rather than hash.
3. It support insertion and lookup, i.e. checking whether it contains a value or not.
4. There is **no** need for deletion, i.e. values will never be remove from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, no, since the Ω(log n) bound on comparisons still applies to comparison-based sets without deletion.

In practice, I'm not aware of any comparison-based structures that yield an empirical improvement, other than that deletion is often more complicated than insertion, and you don't have to code it. (Bloom filters are an example of a hash-based data structure where not having deletion yields a performance improvement.)